# Error 500 en Laravel AJAX Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, modal

espero y tngan un buen dia.

El motivo por el que estoy qui es que tengo un problema Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Estuve leyendo muchos foros incluyendo este donde dicen que usando:
Vista:

```
@push('head')
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
@endpush
```

y en la parte de los scripts agregar:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
</script>
```

Estoy haciendo un model donde tiene que llenar la info, depues al drle click al boton de agregar mando la info. a un AJAX, el AJAS tiene que mandarlo al STORE y asi lo agregaria a la base de datos.
a continuacion les dejo los codigos:

Modal:

```
<div id="create" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="form-group row add">
                        <label for="id_doctor" class="control-label col-sm-2">Doctor: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control col-6" name="id_doctor" id="id_doctor">
                                @foreach($selectDoctor as $registro)
                                <option value="{{ $registro->id }}">{{ $registro->nombre}}
                                    {{ $registro->apellido_paterno}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @foreach($idPaciente as $Key => $Registro)
                    <input id="paciente" name="paciente" value="{{$Registro -> paciente}}" hidden>
                    @endforeach

                    <div class="form-group row add">
                        <label for="fecha_consulta" class="control-label col-sm-2">Fecha de Cita: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_consulta" name="fecha_consulta">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row add">
                        <label for="hora_consulta" class="control-label col-sm-2">Hora de Cita: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora_consulta" name="hora_consulta">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnAgregarCitar">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Agregar</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-rombe">Cerrar</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Seccion de JS:

```
@section('SpecificPluginJs')
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
</script>
<script src="/assets/js/agregarCita.js"></script>
@endsection
```

agregarCita.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.create-modal', function () {
    $('#create').modal('show');
    $('.form-horizontal').show();
    $('.modal-title').text('Agregar Cita');


    var nuevaCita;

    $('#btnAgregarCitar').click(function () {
        recolectarDatos();
        enviarInformacionCita(nuevaCita);
    });


    var fecha = new Date();
    var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    var mes = fecha.getMonth();
    var dia = fecha.getDate();


    function recolectarDatos() {
        nuevaCita = {
            paciente: $('#paciente').val(),
            doctor: $('#id_doctor').val(),
            fecha_cita: anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia,
            fecha_consulta: $('#fecha_consulta').val(),
            hora_consulta: $('#fecha_consulta').val(),
            tipo_cita: 1,
            estatus: 1
        }

        console.log(nuevaCita);
    }

    function enviarInformacionCita(objEvento) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: objEvento,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg) {
                    $('#create').modal('toggle');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error al insertar datos")
            }
        })
    }

})
```

y por ultimo el store

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        cita::firstOnCreate(array(
            "paciente"=>$request->paciente,
            "doctor"=>$request->paciente,
            "fecha_cita"=>$request->fecha_cita,
            "fecha_consulta"=>$request->fecha_consulta,
            "hora_consulta"=>$request->hora_consulta,
            "tipo_cita"=>$request->tipo_cita,
            "estatus"=>$request->estatus
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Un error 500 tiene muchas causas posibles, la respuesta estará probablemente en el log de Laravel.

Comment: alguna recomendacion, soy nuevo en laravel asi que podrias auxiliarme

Comment: Revisar los logs de Laravel en la carpeta storage/logs, y si no hay logs, activar dicha funcionalidad en el archivo .env

Comment: tengo 5 archivos.log y un .gitignore

Comment: Ahí tienes la respuesta, ya no necesitas que te guíe más. Si necesitas más información, lee la documentación o busca en Google.

Comment: Pero que es lo que checare ena esos archivos?

Comment: Realiza la petición y coloca acá el último error que indica el archivo de log de laravel